# Swift Parse and Search Bar not giving results

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uisearchbar

I have a parseTableViewController, parseTableViewCell and UISearchBar outlet on my view. The data comes as expected but when i do search nothing happens and sometimes it crashes the app. Here is my code, there is no error. I think i'm missing a point here.. Thank you

```
import UIKit
import ParseUI
import Parse

class profilTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{

    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "A.png")
    var arka: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arka = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
        arka.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
        arka.clipsToBounds = true
        arka.image = backgroundImage
        arka.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(arka)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(arka)

        tableView.backgroundView = arka

        self.addEffect()
    }
    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        self.parseClassName = "ProfilListesi"
        self.textKey = "profileName"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
    }
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "ProfilListesi")
        if searchBar.text != "" {
            query.whereKey("profileName", containsString: searchBar.text!.lowercaseString)
        }
        query.cachePolicy = .CacheThenNetwork
        query.orderByAscending("profileName")
        query.limit = 1000
        return query
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder() 
        self.loadObjects()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        self.loadObjects()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = "" 
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        self.loadObjects()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> profilTableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profilSegue") as! profilTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = profilTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "profilSegue")
        }
        if let profil = object?["profileName"] as? String {
            cell?.profilLabel?.text = profil
        }
        if let sistem = object?["profileType"] as? String {
            cell?.sistemLabel?.text = sistem
        }
        return cell
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "detaySegue" {
            var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! profilDetayViewController
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let row = Int(indexPath.row)
                detailScene.currentObject = (objects?[row] as! PFObject)
            }
        }
    }

    func addEffect()
    {
        let effect =  UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)

        let effectView  = UIVisualEffectView(effect: effect)

        effectView.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)

        arka.addSubview(effectView)

        arka.layer.cornerRadius = 0

        arka.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: did u fix the problem I've the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm on mobile, I will reply asap

Comment: have you got any answer?

Comment: i declared variable before viewDidLoad like var search = [""], and need to add tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
in the viewDidLoad. That made the trick and sorry for late response